# Change selected characters in a string using loop

Tags: python-3.x, string, loops

I'm writing a function to change the letter case of even letters in a string (spaces/punctuation is ignored). ie, from `"Abcd. Efgh.. Ijkl!"` to `"abCd. efGh.. IJkL!"`

My code only changes the first letter. Initially I thought my issue was the `replace()` function so I switched to the `.append()` function instead but the result still remains the same: `['abcd. Efgh.. Ijkl!']`

How can I change the code to capture the result of each loop?

```py
def mock(string):
    new_string=[]
    new_letter=""
    for letter in string[::2]:
        if letter.islower():
            new_letter= letter.upper()
            new_string.append(string.replace(letter,new_letter))
            
        elif letter.isupper():
            new_letter= letter.lower()
            new_string.append(string.replace(letter,new_letter))

        return new_string

print(mock("Abcd. Efgh.. Ijkl!"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use either `.replace()` or `.append()` but `.replace()` will replace all occurrences (not just even ones). You can rewrite your code as:

```py
def mock(string):
    new_string = []
    for index, letter in enumerate(string):
        new_letter = letter
        if index % 2 == 0:
            if letter.islower():
                new_letter= letter.upper()
            elif letter.isupper():
                new_letter= letter.lower()
        new_string.append(new_letter)
    return "".join(new_string)
```

You could also use a list comprehension. A single line implementation would be

```py
return "".join(s if i%2 else s.swapcase() for i, s in enumerate(string))
```